# Why does devTools profiler show DOMContentLoaded event this way?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

**UPDATE: Even DOMContentloaded and load are showed incorrectly sometimes**
[image]

I don't understand two things:

1. DOMContentLoaded is showed two times in with different timestamps
2. DOMContentLoaded is showed while Parsing HTML (the blue line). As I know it should be fired, after parsing has been completed.

Could you explain it?
[image]

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {
  const x = 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" >

  </head>
  <body style="background-color: black; color: white;">
        <p id='first'>1</p>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <p id='second'>2</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have an extremely long frame (12 seconds) that completely blocks everything including DOM and JS so devtools could have simply miscalculated the position of the overlay indicator.

Comment: @wOxxOm

The same if it's fast. When it's fast it even shows load event earlier DOMContentLoaded(red line is earlier then the blue one, js events are correct). I don't know why

Comment: Well, my point is that it's a bug in devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm seems so. Found the same problem asked on google's website 
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/25495676?hl=en